# Can an API Gateway find URIs of microservices registered on a Service Registry dynamically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

I'm working with Spring Boot and I have an Eureka Server setup where some microservices are registered to for Service Discovery.
Now I would like my API Gateway which I registered as an Eureka Client to redirect to those microservices dynamically instead of hard coding their URIs.

Something like this, where "AuthMicroservice" is the name of an already registered microservice:

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                    .path("/auth/asdh26627s8")
                        //.uri("http://localhost:8080/auth")
                        .uri("http://AuthMicroservice")
                )
                .build();
    }
```

When I try that it tells me there was an "java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'AuthMicroservice' after 2 queries".

So I am wondering is this even possible? If yes, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. All I had to do was replace "http" inside the URI with "lb" to enable Load-balancing.

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p

                    .path("/auth/asdh26627s8")
                        .uri("lb://AuthMicroservice/auth")
                )
                .build();
    }
```